# Comment traduire « arbitrary code execution » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, informatique

On a le [*arbitrary code execution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) dans le domaine de la sécurité informatique dont on dit d'une partie dans une ébauche d'article sur [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_arbitraire) qu'elle consiste en l'« action à faire faire à une machine sans que le propriétaire soit d'accord » ; on trouve la cooccurrence *ACE vulnerability*. On a aussi des emplois dans l'univers du jeu vidéo (« Retrogaming hobbyists have managed to find vulnerabilities in classic video games that allow them to execute arbitrary code [...] », Wikipédia : [exemple](https://youtu.be/wdRJWDKb5Bo)).

Comment traduit-on *arbitrary code execution* ; comment l'agence-t-on avec *vulnérabilité* ; l'instruction (code arbitraire) est-elle *employée* ou *exécutée* ; y a-t-il une formulation uniforme quand on en traite ?

> Cette faille de sécurité repose sur... 
>  Le temps record de ce jeu
>   a été établi en...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je te propose:

> Cette vulnérabilité permet l'exécution de code arbitraire/malveillant<sup>1</sup>.

On pourrait donc compléter tes phrases comme ceci:

> Cette faille de sécurité repose sur l'exploitation d'un débordement de pile (*stack overflow* !) qui permet l'exécution de code malveillant.
>
> ---
>
> Le temps record de ce jeu a été établi en tirant parti d'une faille autorisant l'exécution de code arbitraire.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Malveillant est souvent utilisé mais présuppose que le code en question a de mauvaises intentions alors que du code arbitraire injecté par cette technique pourrait être « bienveillant », en corrigeant un bug par exemple.</sub>

Comment: Proposition acceptée. Je note que tu as employé systématiquement _exécution_ de code arbitraire.

Comment: Oui, "employer" ou "utiliser" du code se dit mais concerne le développeur, ou par extension le programme. Ici, c'est l'exécution du code étranger par la machine cible qui est le point important.

Comment: Pourrait-on employer `quelconque` à la place du mot `arbitraire` ?

Comment: Rien ne l'interdit mais s'il fallait trouver un meilleur qualificatif, je préférerais *exécution de code malveillant*. Je le rajoute d'ailleurs à ma réponse.

Comment: "*du code arbitraire injecté par cette technique pourrait être bienveillant*": En fait non. Une personne entrant la nuit par une fenêtre avec une échelle a des intentions malveillantes, sinon elle sonne à la porte. Pour la correction d'un bug on utilisera un programme légitime surveillé par les moyens de protection mis en place, on n'injectera pas des instructions habillées en données et exécutées grâce à un mécanisme illégitime résultant d'une erreur de programmation. Code malveillant est la traduction de *malware*, contraction de *malicious software*.

Comment: @mins En reprenant ta métaphore, si des pompiers qui n'ont pas les clefs d'une maison montent sur une échelle et défoncent une fenêtre pour aller sauver des personnes en danger immédiat (inondation, incendie, fuite de gaz...), j'évite de dire qu'ils sont malveillants... ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre :-) Ceci dit, les pompiers défoncent les fenêtres après avoir épuisé tous les autres moyens et avec l'aval d'un officier de police attestant de la légitimité. La vie est rarement en jeu dans la production informatique, les corrections urgentes se font en utilisant les méthodes prévues. Dans une entreprise sérieuse une correction ("[patch](https://www.journaldunet.com/solutions/dsi/1032050-security-patch-management-3-3-le-processus-ideal/)") sera mise en oeuvre via une [procédure type ITIL](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestion_des_mises_en_production).

Comment: @mins *...après avoir épuisé tous les autres moyens et avec l'aval d'un officier de police attestant de la légitimité* : C'est vrai, mais pas en cas de force majeure (ex:  incendie, personne ayant fait un malaise cardiaque, tentative de suicide) où l'absence d'intervention peut être qualifiée de non assistance à personne en danger.

Comment: @mins  La vie est parfois en jeu en informatique suivant les domaines dans lesquels on travaille. Ce que je voulais surtout dire est que du code "arbitraire" n'est pas nécessairement du code "malveillant". Utiliser des failles de sécurité pour contourner des bugs d'un programme développé il y a quinze ans et dont les développeurs ou les éditeurs ont disparu et parfois la seule solution, au moins à court terme.